# How to get drawable of an ImageView from a custom spinner?

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have a custom spinner with an ImageView and a TextView, however the return codes do not return either one of these values rather they return it as an object.

How do I get the drawable id or the textview string separately and not the object of the spinner?

Do I have to do it in my adapter, the spinner itself or other components trying to get the data?

Tq

Here is my Spinner XML code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/dark_red_square" /><!--Make sure image is present in Drawable folder-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Demo"
        android:textColor="#000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This spinner is in a fragment. Honestly I don't know what codes should I sample here for reference, but here's the custom adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int[] flags, String[] countryNames, LayoutInflater inflter) {
        this.context = context;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        this.inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return countryNames[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
        TextView spinnerText= convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
        ImageView spinnerImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage);
        spinnerText.setText(countryNames[position]);
        spinnerImage.setImageResource(flags[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: by drawable I mean the id of the drawable as an int

Comment: edited, but honestly I don't know if it suffices

Comment: on what step do you want to get the id of the drawable?

Comment: I want the calling activity to get the drawable id of the selected item from the spinner